# What happens when a cron'ed PHP script hasn't finished but cron hit it again?

Tags: php, cron

Suppose we have a PHP script that takes more time to process than its cron interval. PHP script: takes 2 mins to complete a task. Cron: calls that script in 1 minute interval.

What happens? Does that script gets instantiated again, so a new copy of the scripts get executed, and the running ones are left running until finished?

Or the "current" live one gets killed and recalled again?

Thx

Comment: That depends how the script is written and how you call it, but in general you'll end up with multiple copies of the script running concurrently.